# How can I revert to a previous version of my app in git ...?

Tags: git, revert

I use a push to deploy on a godaddy server.  This strategy of course uses a checkout on each push to deploy the working directory to public_html.

Can I ssh in to the server and just checkout different "points in time".

I don't use branching. I mean I only use "master" branches so the development timeline is 100% linear.

What is the command to do this?

Comment: Do you know the hash of the commit you want to revert to?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I ssh in to the server and just checkout different "points in time".

Yep,

If you want to checkout code at the given commit id use:

```
git checkout <commit id>
```

If you want to "remove" (undo) changes :

```
git revert commit1 commit2. .. commit n
git push origin master
```

#### Last but dangerous way: (rebase)

```
git reset HEAD --hard <commit id>
```

This will remove your commits and when you push you will lose all your changes + all your fellow will have to delete their master and to check it out again.

So you should go with the first way :-)

Comment: it's not working ... I tried `git checkout cf9` ... I'm assuming by commit id you mean the commit hash and I'm assuming it does not need quotes.